# How to dynamically resize a label inside a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, resize, wpf-controls, label

I need to know how I could dynamically resize a `label` in a WPF application.

---

I've already found a sample [in this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71792/WPF-Draggable-Label) which has already achieved both dragging and resizing a label at the same time.
I dug into the code, and to make it short, I found out that inside `OnMouseMove` event of the label, it checks the mouse cursor shape and if it was `Hand` it will do the dragging and if it was either of the `resizing arrows` it will do the resizing correspondingly.
Check it out. you'll see.
In this certain example I couldn't manage to find out how the cursor shape changes to `resizing arrows` when the mouse is hovered on the label's border.

**So**

I either need to find out *'how I could change the mouse cursor shape to resizing arrows when hovered on a label's border'*, **OR** to find a new approach to resize a label, dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the cursor is done via the `this.Cursor` property.

I opened the code in the article and saw how they do it...

In the `OnMouseMove` the cursor is changed if the left mouse button is **NOT** clicked:

```
Point currentLocation = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(wnd);
       ......
       ......
const int dragHandleWidth = 3;

var bottomHandle = new Rect(0, height - dragHandleWidth, width, dragHandleWidth);
var rightHandle = new Rect(width - dragHandleWidth, 0, dragHandleWidth, height);

Point relativeLocation = wnd.TranslatePoint(currentLocation, this);

if (rightHandle.Contains(relativeLocation))
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
}
else if (bottomHandle.Contains(relativeLocation))
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
}
else
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

In other words, they check if the current mouse location is within 3 px of the bottom or right border, if it is, they change the cursor accordingly...

You can easily change this logic to suite your needs....

Comment: What does `this` refer to in this line?

`Point relativeLocation = wnd.TranslatePoint(currentLocation, this);` anyway ?

Comment: Here you go [this keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But somehow it didn't work :(
Can you please tell me what `Rect()` really makes ? and how can I make sure that it really is there in the `Grid` of my app ? like making it black or giving it a border ?

Comment: and since I'm doing everything inside WPF (not Wininforms) I need to know what this line `Point relativeLocation = wnd.TranslatePoint(currentLocation, this);
` is supposed to do.
Thank you a lot ;)

Comment: currentLocation is the mouse position ***relative to the window***. What this line does is translates the coordinates to be *relative to the label itself* . This is done so you can know if the mouse position is within the border of the label.

Comment: Thanks A lot !! It's working. It can determine whether the mouse is located on the left or the bottom border of the label AND will change the cursor correspondingly, as desired. However, when the mouse leaves the `Label`, the cursor will still remain a `resizing arrow`.
I used a lot of mouse events on the grid,label etc. but none of them seem to work properly to reset the cursor to the default `arrow` when it's not on the label or any of the borders.
Do you have the best solution for that dear Blachshma ?

Comment: Sounds like a new question, as this question was about *How to dynamically size a label*. But out of the back of my head I'd create a new region: `var labelHandle = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);` and check if `labelHandle .Contains(relativeLocation);`